# How can I encode a plaintext configuration file then `tee` it into its destination?

Tags: text-processing, tee

I have a vanilla configuration for Nginx (`nginx.conf`) in plaintext format. It has Latin characters, space indents and is ~250 lines total. I use it when I compile Nginx from source. After the source is compiled, I use a text editor to create the (empty) `nginx.conf`, then copy & paste the vanilla configuration, save it, and bounce Nginx to use the vanilla config. This action of copy & paste into the editor is somewhat cumbersome alongside the automated components of the build process.

The vanilla configuration file is local to me (at least for the foreseeable future), not online. Accordingly, this makes `curl` or `wget` off limits. I would ideally like to encode my vanilla `nginx.conf` as a single string and then `tee` (or similar) it into the server-side `nginx.conf`, bypassing the open-copy-paste-save-exit dance.

The workflow would then be:

1. acquire and compile Nginx source
2. build Nginx scaffolding
3. *create `nginx.conf` automatically by piping a pre-encoded string into `tee` (or similar)*
4. bounce Nginx

How could I approach step 3, please?

Comment: I guess `base64` would be the easiest approach - but I do not understand why you're not overwriting the config after building with the correct one?

Comment: Why can't you use `cp` or `scp`?

Comment: @Panki - to clarify: when I compile Nginx from source, I truncate the provided `nginx.conf` so I can use my own. It's this process that involves the open-copy-paste-save-exit part that I'd rather automate. Thank you for the `base64` approach, I'll look into that now.

Comment: @roaima - I use Terminal on macOS to compile Nginx on the remote Debian server, so I'm doing this in an `ssh` session.

Comment: Just use `scp` then. It can copy your local file into your remote machine. So, no need to do "open-copy-paste-save-exit"

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `tee` to your remote server

```
ssh user@remote tee /path/to/nginx.conf < local-nginx.conf
```

This assumes that the remote `/path/to/nginx.conf` is writable by your remote user.

Append `> /dev/null` to suppress the stdout.

Comment: @roaima thanks for the input, edited it.

Answer (score 1):

In [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/750630/how-can-i-encode-a-plaintext-configuration-file-then-tee-it-into-its-destinati?noredirect=1#comment1428097_750630) you explained that you build the Nginx application on a remote server (connecting with `ssh`), but that you have the `nginx.conf` configuration file saved on your local machine.

In this case, use `scp` from your local machine to the remote system to copy the configuration file directly:

```
ssh rUser@rHost                              # Connect to remote system
… build nginx etc …

scp my_nginx.conf rUser@rHost:nginx.conf    # Copy from current directory to $HOME on remote
```

The `scp` command takes an optional path to the destination (relative to the remote user's `$HOME` if the path does not begin with `/`). If you don't have direct permission to write to the target file (and you can't `scp` to `root@rHost`), you can use `ssh` with `sudo` instead. But this is much uglier, since we can't simply pipe across *stdin* and also allow a password to be entered for `sudo`:

```
scp my_nginx.conf rUser@rHost:/tmp/nginx.conf.$$ &&
    ssh -t rUser@rHost "sudo sh -c 'cat /tmp/nginx.conf.$$ >/etc/nginx.conf'; rm -f /tmp/nginx.conf.$$"
```

The `ssh … sudo sh -c '…'` construct gives space to restart Nginx too, if so desired